# Grub4Dos booting ISO's via 2nd Partition

Tags: partitioning, multi-boot, grub, iso-image

Im looking for a way to temporary map an ISO to a partition VIA Grub

Basically have 110GB External USB 2.0 Hard Drive that stores mainly ISO's and some Installable software such as Windows Office etc.

Usually with Grub Loader its used for booting static partition on the hard drive but i want to be able to add a menu called **"Windows 7 Corporate Build 1100 (Installtion)"** and when selected it will use the ISO File stored `\Operating Systems\Windows\7\Professional\en_windows_7_corp_1100.iso` and map it to the 2nd partition on the external drive.

The partition would be made up of a `100GB` and a `10GB`

Id do not wish to use `initrd` as some images are several gigabytes.

But I also wan to use that partition for booting other data so it should only be temporary and data should be cleaned before a new iso is "Mounted"

So my question is:

**How can I map an ISO to secondary partition on the external disk, Followed by booting that partition**

Any help is appreciated!